# A more efficient way to iterate over multiple DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create custom DataFrame that will represent all missing (NaN) values in my data.

Solution I came up with works, but it is slow and ineffective over a set with 300 rows and 50 columns.

Pandas Version = "0.24.2"

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'city_code'     : ['Sydney2017', 'London2017', 'Sydney2018', 'London2018'],
    'population_mil': [5.441, 7.375, pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan]
}


class NaNData:

    def __init__(self, data: dict):
        self.data: dict = data

    @property
    def data_df(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """ Returns input data as a DataFrame. """

        return pd.DataFrame(self.data)

    def select_city(self, city_code: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """ Creates DataFrame where city_code column value matches
        requested city_code string. """

        df = self.data_df
        return df.loc[df['city_code'] == city_code]

    @property
    def df(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        """ Creates custom summary DataFrame to represent missing data. """

        data_df = self.data_df

        # There are duplicates in 'city_code' column. Make sure your cities
        # are unique values only.
        all_cities = list(set(data_df['city_code']))

        # Check whether given city has any NaN values in any column.
        has_nan = [
            self.select_city(i).isnull().values.any() for i in all_cities
        ]

        data = {
            'cities' : all_cities,
            'has_NaN': has_nan,
        }

        df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        return df


nan_data = NaNData(data)
print(nan_data.df)

# Output:
#        cities  has_NaN
# 0  London2018     True
# 1  London2017    False
# 2  Sydney2018     True
# 3  Sydney2017    False
```

I feel like the way I approach iteration in pandas is not right. Is there a proper (or common) solution for this kind of problem? Should I be somehow using groupby for these kind of operations?

Any input is very appreciated,
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over multiple dataframes to obtaion your result, you can indeed use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'city_code'     : ['Sydney2017', 'London2017', 'Sydney2018', 'London2018'],
    'population_mil': [5.441, 7.375, pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan],
    'temp': [28, pd.np.nan, 24, 25]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.groupby('city_code').apply(lambda x: x.isna().any()).any(axis=1)
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear in my question - I have provided you with data that only has two columns, 'city_code', and 'population_mil' but data set I am working with has many more columns. What I am looking for, is NaN values not only in 'population_mil' column, but in any column that are present in dataset. How would I apply x.isna().any() to check in every column, and not just 'population_mil'?

Comment: Your question is - how to check that a city has any `pd.np.nan` in any column in any row (that belongs to that city)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for

Comment: Added it to my answer - it's even simpler now.

Comment: Solved. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the isna() function to do the na check:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.assign(has_NaN=df.population_mil.isna()).drop('population_mil',1)


    city_code   has_NaN
0   Sydney2017  False
1   London2017  False
2   Sydney2018  True
3   London2018  True
```

Comment: Note that the OP wanted to check for cities that repeat multiple times in the dataset: "  # There are duplicates in 'city_code' column. Make sure your cities are unique values only. ", which they accounted for by `all_cities = list(set(data_df['city_code']))`.

Comment: (@Kirill Chemeritsin, for clarity's sake your example should've included a city that is duplicated in the dataset)